# C++: Trouble with tr1::bind (C2065)

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-errors

I'm getting a compiler error with `bind`:

```
using namespace std;

bool odp(int arg1, int arg2);

// ...

find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), tr1::bind(odp, iValue, _1)); // C2065
```

My goal is to curry `odp()`, so its first argument is `iValue`, and apply that function in `find_if`.

The error:

```
C2065: '_1' : undeclared identifier.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `using namespace std::tr1::placeholders` or `using std::tr1::placeholders::_1`.

Answer (score 1):

2 things here.... 1st of all, it's entirely possible your compiler does not support TR1. Visual Studio 2008, for example, does not support TR1, unless you install [Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=27673c47-b3b5-4c67-bd99-84e525b5ce61&displaylang=en).

Second, I believe you need a namespace qualification for `_1`.